# Attachments still in exported EmailMessage after Removing them

Tags: c#, attachment, exchangewebservices

Why are the attachments still in the exported .eml file after I have removed them?

```
GetItemResponse i;
EmailMessage item = (EmailMessage)i.Item;

item.Attachments.Clear();
item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);

string filename = $"{item.Subject}.eml";

using (var fileStream = new FileStream($@"C:\{filename}", FileMode.Create))
{
    fileStream.Write(item.MimeContent.Content, 0, item.MimeContent.Content.Length);
}
```

Comment: `MimeContent` is cached and you need to reload the message from exchange

Comment: I see. I'm not looking to change the item in exchange I just wanted to remove them from the EMailMessage object before output.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible through `EmailMessage`. You can use a MIME library like MimeKit.